# INDEX & MATCH array formula to pull data based off of one criteria OR another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of data that I want to pull particular data out of based off a letter in one column OR a number in another. I've set up two different array formulas to pull the data I want, but I want to make one list with all the data but I can't figure out how to make one formula that will pull the data that EITHER matches a letter in one column OR  that mathces a number in different column.

Here's the formula that I have that pulls two different lists that I want to have as one list:

In A2

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Raw Data'!$A$3:$M$2548, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF('Raw Data'!$A$1,'Raw Data'!$F$3:$F$2548), MATCH(ROW('Raw Data'!$A$3:$M$2548), ROW('Raw Data'!$A$3:$M$2548)), ""), ROWS($A$2:F8)),COLUMNS('Raw Data'!$A$3:F9)),"")
```

In O2

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX('Raw Data'!$A$3:$M$2548, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF('Raw Data'!$G$1,'Raw Data'!$G$3:$G$2548), MATCH(ROW('Raw Data'!$A$3:$M$2548), ROW('Raw Data'!$A$3:$M$2548)), ""), ROWS($O2:O$2)),COLUMNS('Raw Data'!$A$3:A3)),"")
```

How can I combine those two in order to get one list instead of two seperate lists?

Here's a sample of the raw data:

[image: raw data]

How I'd like to see it come out:

[image: Like This]

Comment: have you tried using `SUMPRODUCT`?

Comment: Hi @Ben H. better share some sample data along with expected output, help us to fix the issue !!

Comment: Done, added data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE instead of SMALL(IF(MATCH( to supply the row number into INDEX.

```
=INDEX('Raw Data'!A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($3:$2548)/SIGN(('Raw Data'!F$3:F$2548=F$1)+('Raw Data'!G$3:G$2548=G$1)), ROW(1:1)))
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to drag it across for additional columns then you probably have to change part of the formula to `SIGN(('Raw Data'!$F$3:$F$2548=$F$1)+('Raw Data'!$G$3:$G$2548=G$1))`. A cursory examination of the formulas that didn't work should have shown that the columns were shifting.

Comment: I actually figured that out after my comment. Thanks. However, what if I wanted to be able to sort and filter the results?

Comment: That would be better as a new question as it raises the possibility that Advanced Filter or an SQL query might be more suited to the task at hand.